# How does cocoapods determine which files from source to keep in installation?

Tags: git, frameworks, cocoapods, dependency-management

As an example, let's use the [AdColony](http://adcolony.com) video ad platform. I put `pod 'AdColony'` into my `Podfile` and after running `pod install`, my `Pods` directory has an `AdColony` folder in it (and the Xcode project is configured to be able to use it).

Now, that folder contains two items: the `AdColony.framework` iOS framework, and a README.md file. Exactly what you need, right? However, things get mysterious when diving a little bit deeper.

The [AdColony Cocoapods page](https://cocoapods.org/pods/AdColony) has a [link](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/c/8/4/AdColony/3.2.1/AdColony.podspec.json) to the Podspec. In it, we have the following entry:

```
"source": {
"git": "https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK-3.git",
"tag": "v3.2.1"
}
```

If you go to the github project and tag, you will see that it has the contents of the pod, but it also has other stuff: a `SampleApps` folder, a `CHANGELOG.md` file, and a W-9 PDF. None of those appear in the Pods directory.

If you delete the pod not just from the project, but from your computer's cache, and run `pod install --verbose`, you will see the git command in the console. It looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/AdColony/AdColony-iOS-SDK-3.git
 /var/folders/jp/lm8trz8d7nl1pf4_mh690dvr0000gn/T/d20180112-57517-1j1p7dc
 --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch v3.2.1
```

Running that command myself (minus the random string of a destination path) produces a folder with everything you see on the github page---the `SampleApps` folder, etc.

Somewhere between this clone process and the placing of the `AdColony` folder into my project's `Pods` directory, cocoapods removed the unnecessary files.

When does this happen?

How does cocoapods know which files to remove and which to keep?

Is this controllable by the developer? If so, how?

Is any of this documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does that behind the hood in Cocoapods. What it does is it fetches the podspec from your framework - which the podspec would define the necessary files `minus` the SampleApp.

Try going to the [podspec](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html) and look for `public_header`, `frameworks` or `source_file` (if the git contains any source).

I urge you to create a sample pod on your local workspace and play around with it :)

Comment: Yep - the podspec defines what files gets copied.

Comment: Is the README.md file included by default, even if not listed in the podspec?

Comment: Yes, README.md is included.